# train model in a for loop with different batch sizes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I tried `for` looping the batch sizes to know the effect of batch sizes in the model.

```
print ('train_X', train_X.shape)
print ('test_X', test_X.shape)
print ('train_Y', train_Y.shape)
print ('test_Y', test_Y.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=size, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7))


batch_sizes = [32,64,128,256,512]
for batch_size in batch_sizes:  

  model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error")

  history = model.fit(train_X,
            train_Y,
            epochs=3,
            validation_data=(test_X, test_Y),
            batch_size=batch_size,
            verbose=2)
```

It did work well for the first batch size, but then it failed. Please see the validation loss.

```
Epoch 1/3
212/212 - 8s - loss: 0.4929 - val_loss: 0.1251
Epoch 2/3
212/212 - 7s - loss: 0.0121 - val_loss: 0.3445
Epoch 3/3
212/212 - 7s - loss: 0.0114 - val_loss: 0.2329
```

The second loop failed with strange `val_loss`.

```
Epoch 1/3
106/106 - 6s - loss: 0.3061 - val_loss: 694288384.0000
Epoch 2/3
106/106 - 6s - loss: 0.0114 - val_loss: 694312320.0000
Epoch 3/3
106/106 - 5s - loss: 0.0108 - val_loss: 694323264.0000
```

Any idea to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your above train setup, after the first batch training, the rest of the training would take pre-trained weights. So, you should initiate your model for each batch training to receive the batch effect on your models. Here is some pointer of your need.

**Dummy Data**

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense 
import numpy as np 

# dummies 
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000, 10))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000, 7))

X.shape, y.shape
((1000, 10), (1000, 7))
```

**Model list**

```
# first model 
def model_a():
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(7, activation='linear'))
    return model 

# second model etc
def model_b():
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=10, activation='elu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='elu'))
    model.add(Dense(7, activation='linear'))
    return model 

# get all model 
models = [model_a(), model_b()]
```

**Training**

```
# looping 
for i in range(len(models)):
    print("-"*50)

    for batch_size in [32,64,128,256,512]:  
        print('\nbs ', batch_size)

        model = models[i]
        model.compile('adam', loss='mse')

        history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3,
                            validation_split=0.1,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            verbose=2)
```

```
--------------------------------------------------

bs  32
Epoch 1/3
29/29 - 1s - loss: 0.2733 - val_loss: 0.1663

bs  64
Epoch 1/3
15/15 - 0s - loss: 0.0931 - val_loss: 0.0919

bs  128
Epoch 1/3
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.0895 - val_loss: 0.0893

...

--------------------------------------------------

bs  32
Epoch 1/3
29/29 - 0s - loss: 0.2007 - val_loss: 0.1080

bs  64
Epoch 1/3
15/15 - 0s - loss: 0.0907 - val_loss: 0.0883

bs  128
Epoch 1/3
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.0876 - val_loss: 0.0857

...
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the need of `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`